# Border radius has weird edges - react native

Tags: react-native

When I style a `TouchableOpacity` like below, I get strange rendering in the iPhone 6 simulator. Any idea why?

Styles:

```
buttonContainer: {
  height: 50,
  borderColor: black,
  borderRadius: 25,
  margin: 2,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  backgroundColor: coral
}
```

Component:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}
  onPress={this.signIn}
>
  <Text style={styles.button}>Sign in</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[image]

Comment: smells like the margin causes it? what happens if you delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the text had its own background color. Made it transparent and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow: hidden` to your styles. Or try removing the margin.